# PHP session cookie resets on page refresh

Tags: php, session, cookies

I had a working web page with login functionality based on PHP session. Recently I have noticed that in some browsers (Google Chrome desktop, Vivaldi) I am not able to login. After some prying I have noticed that the session cookie changes on every redirect / page refresh. This does not happen in mobile browsers nor in Edge. Anonymous Chrome window also works.

I have tried disabling all extensions, but nothing changed. What might be important though is that my server (Apache) runs on http, not https.

I am not really sure what to show you. The code has not changed for a year and it worked month ago. What changed is the server configuration - namely `session.save_path` collides with `open_basedir`. But that shouldn't affect just SOME browsers. I've been searching for a few hours already and I don't know what to think of this.

EDIT: Very interesting! I have been checking the cookies using the info icon. When I open the application panel in devtools, the cookie is not set at all.

Session config:

```
Session Support enabled
Registered save handlers         files user
Registered serializer handlers   php_serialize php php_binary wddx
session.auto_start               Off
session.cache_expire             180
session.cache_limiter            nocache
session.cookie_domain            no value
session.cookie_httponly          no value
session.cookie_lifetime          0
session.cookie_path              /
session.cookie_secure            0
session.gc_divisor               1000
session.gc_maxlifetime           1440
session.gc_probability           1
session.lazy_write               On
session.name                     PHPSESSID
session.referer_check            no value
session.save_handler             files
session.save_path                E:\xampp\tmp
session.serialize_handler        php
session.sid_bits_per_character   5
session.sid_length               26
session.upload_progress.cleanup  On
session.upload_progress.enabled  On
session.upload_progress.freq     1%
session.upload_progress.min_freq    1
session.upload_progress.name     PHP_SESSION_UPLOAD_PROGRESS
session.upload_progress.prefix   upload_progress_
session.use_cookies              1
session.use_only_cookies         1
session.use_strict_mode          0
session.use_trans_sid            0
```

Comment: If you check your browser's storage, is the PHPSESSID cookie created ?
If so, can we have more information about your configuration ? Can you show us the session part of a phpinfo() ?

Answer (score -1):

I think that "some" browsers cache the content and keep the old "session" alive, while others don't and request/check for a new one after every refresh. I may be completely wrong, but that is my idea on it.

Comment: Thanks for sharing idea but please use the comment section for it if you have doubt about the answer. If it works for OP you can post it as answer

Comment: It says i must have 50 rep for being able to comment on original post, I can however comment on my own answer.

Comment: I'm not sure what this would mean for my php code. I already call `session_start()` at the beginning of every file, which should resume existing session. And chrome works in anonymous mode